# Direct proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$.

Tags: irrational-numbers

> Prove that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational using direct proof.

I have seen **TONS** indirect proofs (e.g. proof by contradiction) for it, and people say that it's difficult to proof this directly. So is this impossible?

Thank you.

Comment: You can apply the Eisenstein criterion to the polynomial $X^2-2$.

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean by a "direct proof"?

The most direct argument I can think of for showing that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational uses continued fractions. $\sqrt{2}$ has an infinite continued fraction (namely: $[1,2,2,2,...,]$) and can as such not be rational.

Answer (score 1):

1) wikipedia has given a constructive proof, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2

2) all rational numbers have a finite continued fraction expression, but $\sqrt2$ doesn't

Answer (score 0):

It has an *infinite* continued fraction.

$$ \!\ \sqrt{2} = 1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \ddots}}}}. $$

Comment: Yes, but is your proof that an infinite continued fraction must represent an irrational a direct proof or a proof by contradiction?

Comment: @JohnWordsworth: I don't see how it can be classified under *Proof by contradiction*?, rather it can't be called *direct proof*  also.