# The irrationality of the square root of 2

Tags: irrational-numbers

Is there a proof to the irrationality of the square root of 2 besides using the argument that a rational number is expressed to be p/q?

Comment: Pretty much the definition of _rational_ number implies a _ratio_ of two integers.  Do you want to propose another definition for rational?

Comment: Using the rational root theorem, you can prove that $x^2-2=0$ has no rational roots. Since $\sqrt 2$ is a root of this quadratic equation, you can claim that it's irrational

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked before. Please search Math.SE for an answer to your question before asking.

Regardless, yes, there are lots of ways to prove the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. Here are some pertinent resources:

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32011/direct-proof-of-irrationality/32017#32017 (That's a really neat proof of the type for which you are looking.)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality
- [Direct proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395500/direct-proof-for-the-irrationality-of-sqrt-2?rq=1)
- [Irrationality proofs not by contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/irrationality-proofs-not-by-contradiction)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overkill proof: $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's =].

Answer (score 0):

If $\sqrt 2=p/q$ where $gcd(p,q)=1$ then $2=p^2/q^2$ <=>$p^2=2q^2$ and thus $p^2$ is even and thus $p$ is even let's say $p=2m$. Then $4m^2=2q^2$<=> $q^2=2m^2$  and thus $q$ is also even. So $gcd(p,q)>1$ which is false